# Windows Search doesn't return all results from parent folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, file-server, search, mappeddrive

We have an issue with Windows Search since we moved the file server from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2. I do have Windows Search installed and the shares indexed (almost 1 million files and I have re-indexed the files).

From the mapped drives on workstations we are finding that it is not returning all results. For example I can search `withdraw` but it doesn't find the files `withdraw v2` or `withdraw v3`.

What I have found out is these files are about 3 to 5 levels deep from the root of the mapped drive. If I go from the root to one level up and search then it finds the file, however searching from the root it doesn't find it.

This is creating a big problem. How can I fix this behavior so that complete search results are returned from the parent folder?

Comment: Does the same behavior occur for searched performed directly on the server? What OS are the workstations running?

Comment: The server is 2012 r2 and the client is Windows 7 pro. When I search on the server it shows up instantly (indexing). When I search from the client it takes about 1 minute and it does show about 111 results but it is missing! 

Just recently I have tried a new workstation joined to the domain and a new user and I get the same results.

I'm running out of ideas and may need to open a case with Microsoft.. argh

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rebuilding the index on the server, making sure it was using DFS, and it started working again. I already rebuilt the index on the server before so i'm not sure what this worked this time.